# Draw Overlay underneath Navigation Bar

Tags: android

How can an overlay (of type `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`) be drawn underneath the Navigation bar in Android?

I'm trying to cover the entire screen with a translucent view that allows users to interact with the UI underneath the overlay, but the Navigation bar retains its color.

The status bar was not an issue since I used the following flag - `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS`

**I'm trying to achieve the above using the following code -**

```
overlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorOverlayGray)
overlay.fitsSystemWindows = false

val layoutFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
} else {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
}

val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    layoutFlag,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)
params.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
windowManager.addView(overlay, params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was that I was using `MATCH_PARENT` as the height, but the height needs to be greater than that.

So now I'm calculating the height of the screen as such -

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
```

And adding the height of the system navigation bar to that.
(Please note that the following code will work in an activity)

```
var navBarHeight = 0
window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets ->
    navBarHeight = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
    view.onApplyWindowInsets(insets)
}
```

And now setting the `LayoutParams` as such -

```
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    height + navBarHeight,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of the display, including navbar, with `getRealMetrics()`:

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)
        val overlayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
        val overlayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

then create window params:

```
params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        overlayWidth,
        overlayHeight,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        OVERLAY_FLAGS,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )
```